# Logging TLS related data in IIS logs for Azure App Service

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have a 4.7 .Net Framework application running in an Azure App Service. I wanted to track some TLS related data in my IIS logs in the same way that I would in a VM, as explained [here](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2017/09/07/new-iis-functionality-to-help-identify-weak-tls-usage/). I've added the IIS Manager site extension and xdt transform file as outlined [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples) -

If I navigate to the D:\local\Config\applicationhost.config through Kudu I can see my config file looks to be transformed as expected but the IIS log files are missing the relevant headers.
Expected Headers:

- crypt-protocol
- crypt-cipher
- crypt-hash
- crypt-keyexchange

Is this functionality actually supported by the App Services, there is a discussion about it [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f2a538e3-3461-4132-b9b7-e694d4bfed9e/add-custom-http-log-fields-in-azure-web-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) but it isn't definitive if the functionality is supported or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this functionality actually supported by the App Services, there is a discussion about it here but it isn't definitive if the functionality is supported or not

It not support now. You could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/17207861-custom-request-headers-in-web-server-logs) to promote this feature to be achieved.